# Using pipe in Windows PowerShell when scripting

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I need to create scripts that manipulate files and their contents. If I use Windows Powershell, the following command perfectly works:

```
(Get-Content my_file.txt).Replace("aaa","bbb") | Set-Content my_file.txt
```

This command will replace any occurence of `aaa` by `bbb`. Yet, I would like to wrap this into a script file that I named `rename.cmd`. The content of the file is

```
CMD (Get-Content my_file.txt).Replace("aaa","bbb") | Set-Content my_file.txt
```

Now, if I type `.\rename.cmd` in PowerShell, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\me\> .\rename.cmd
'Set-Content' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Your mismatching two different script languages. You store your PowerShell code as batch, this will not work. Save your PowerShell code as ps1 file and run that.

Comment: If it is just one line of powershell in a batch script, why not just execute the command directly instead of calling a ps1 file?

Comment: As a single line command in a batch file, you can use ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content 'my_file.txt').Replace('aaa','bbb') | Set-Content 'my_file.txt'"```, or ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content \"my_file.txt\").Replace(\"aaa\",\"bbb\") | Set-Content \"my_file.txt\""```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'CMD' file is for CMD scripts (/the WinNT extension of 'BAT'/Batch files/scripts) - run by 'Cmd.exe' (/previously by 'Command.com' in the distant DOS past).

You need to change your script to have a 'PS1' file extension, so it's named 'Rename.ps1' instead - so it will be run by the correct interpreter/shell - 'PowerShell.exe'.

(But then you might then reach the point of wanting to declare/pass-in arguments to your script.)

Comment: As is mentioned above, you can also execute powershell commands in a batch script with a .cmd (or .bat) extension, if you have some reason to do so. Such commands can have the format of `%__APPDIR__%windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass /command "your_powershell_commands_here"`

Comment: @Qwerty Indeed.  But you might be better starting with 'RemoteSigned' as the execution-policy - at least in terms of providing others a command to run, and similar to the other arguments you can use a '-'/hyphen for the 'Command' argument, i.e. '-Command'.  (I'm guessing that in a few cases you might want to run it against a profile.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not aware of a difference between .bat, .cmd and .ps1 extensions until today. I come from the UNIX world where most of frameworks are quite uniformly standardized and I'm quite impressed of Microsoft historical choices.